# Matrix multiplication with Prolog

Tags: matrix, prolog

I have to write a predicate the predicate `product/3` which receives two matrix and returns the matrix multiplication of them if possible or fail otherwise. (This means if the matrices fullfill the requirement `[n x p] [p x y]`, then return the multiplication with dimensions `[n x y]`)

Example:

```
product(M1, M2, R)
    ?- product([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], [[1,1,1],[1,1,1]], M).
    M = [[3, 3, 3], [7, 7, 7], [11, 11, 11]];
    No
```

For this I have two codes that index the nth row on a matrix `rowI` and that index the nth column `columnI` (I explain how they work in the code below).

```
%Predicate: rowI(M, I, RI)
%Input      rowI([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], 2, RI).
%           RI = [3,4];

rowI([H|_],1,H):-!.
rowI([_|T],I,X) :-
    I1 is I-1,
    rowI(T,I1,X).

%        columnJ(M, J, CJ)
%Input   columnJ([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], 1, CJ).
%        CJ = [1,3,5];

columnJ([],_,[]).
columnJ([H|T], I, [R|X]):-
    rowI(H, I, R), 
    columnJ(T,I,X).


product([H|T], M2, [R|X]):-

    columnJ(M2, C, Z),
    mult(H, Z , X),
    product(T, M2 , X).
```

I was thinking somehow by grabbing the head of the `M1` (which will be each row) and then multiplied for each column in `M2` and after adding the multiplication this list will be the new row. So (C would have to be a counter starting from 1 to the length of `M2`and then `mult` I was just thinking on having it multiplying the lists. (mult is not defined at this point, just a guess).

Here I am trying to explain the way I am thinking it.. but there may be a simplier way. What do you think?

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687499/matrix-multiplication-prolog

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compact code (with the help of higher order constructs maplist and foldl).
I left on purpose the expressions unevaluated, so the result could be reused in more general context:

```
:- module(matrix_multiply,
    [matrix_multiply/3
    ,dot_product/3
    ]).
:- use_module(library(clpfd), [transpose/2]).

%%  matrix_multiply(+X,+Y,-M) is det.
%
%   X(N*P),Y(P*M),M(N*M)
%
matrix_multiply(X,Y,M) :-
    transpose(Y,T),
    maplist(row_multiply(T),X,M).

row_multiply(T,X,M) :-
    maplist(dot_product(X),T,M).

dot_product([X|Xs],[T|Ts],M) :-
    foldl(mul,Xs,Ts,X*T,M).
mul(X,T,M,M+X*T).
```

*edit*

usage (save in a file named matrix_multiply.pl):

```
?- [matrix_multiply].
?- matrix_multiply([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], [[1,1,1],[1,1,1]],R),maplist(maplist(is),C,R).
R = [[1*1+2*1, 1*1+2*1, 1*1+2*1], [3*1+4*1, 3*1+4*1, 3*1+4*1], [5*1+6*1, 5*1+6*1, 5*1+6*1]],
C = [[3, 3, 3], [7, 7, 7], [11, 11, 11]].
```

The numeric evaluation is explicitly requested by `,maplist(maplist(is),C,R)`.
R holds the symbolic expressions, C the values.

*edit*

Just to note that dependency from clpfd:transpose is easy to remove: here is an alternative 'one-liner' definition based on nth/3 and library(yall)

```
mat_transpose([R1|Rs],T) :- findall(V,(
    nth1(Col,R1,_),
    maplist({Col}/[R,C]>>nth1(Col,R,C),[R1|Rs],V)),T).
```